# Combating adverse effects of garlic and onions

Tags: onions, garlic

I'm a huge fan of garlic and onions and seldom do I cook for myself without adding one of the two.

Recently, I've managed to come across a local garlic grower. The intensity of the taste is like nothing I've had before, but the problem of eating it in quantities that I do has become self-evident in my bedroom, which was probably one of the rare occasions that I've felt happy of waking up alone.

I've had difficulties with my body odor previously and I would usually stop eating garlic and onions two days before exposing myself to potential embarrassment, occasionally even substituting my garlic of choice with the bland Chinese garlic sooner than that, but the garlic I'm eating now seems to take close to a full week to clear out.

Is there anything I can do to prepare the garlic to help manage the [allicin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allicin) contained within? So far I'm having some luck adding it to soups, as the prolonged exposure to heat seems to raise the internal temperature of the crushed cloves enough, but mixing into sour cream and letting it sit for a while doesn't seem to be doing enough.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/367/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7836/67

Comment: While your solution relies on kitchen preparation and cooking skills, the underlying problem and solution are based on not only your unique physiology but also a general understanding of health and interactions between the body and various compounds (off-topic). An answer to this question would appear to be some kind of answer to body odor; I recommend you reframe this as a more empirical question.

Comment: Someone exuding cheese and garlic is not as horrendous as someone evaporating like a pickle.

Answer (score 2):

Roasting garlic mellows the taste and bite quite a bit; have you tried using the supergarlic roasted?

You don't need special equipment; just cut the top off of a bulb, dip or rub some cooking oil (I use grapeseed; others use EVOO) on the cut surface, wrap it in foil and and place it in your oven at 350 to 375 F (176 to 190 C) for about 40-45 minutes.

The garlic will squish easily out of the individual cloves. Roasting breaks down those harsh chemicals so they don't mix like they would when you crush a raw clove, so hopefully they wouldn't affect your body odor as pronouncedly.