# How to store garlic?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, food-preservation

When I buy garlic, I normally put it in a bowl on the kitchen counter or in the pantry, and then pop off cloves as need.  Sometimes, if the garlic has been around for a while, I find what looks like green sprouts inside / popping out of the cloves.  What is the best way to keep my garlic fresh?

Comment: For a discussion of the green sprouts, see this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5031/should-one-always-use-the-whole-garlic-clove/5034#5034.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always store mine in the pantry. I use it frequently enough that sprouting is rarely an issue. If you need it to last longer you can freeze garlic, though I have never needed to.

**Shelf Life**

An unbroken bulb of garlic can last 3-5 months in a cool (55-60 F) dark place. Once broken, the remaining cloves last only about 7-10 days.

Frozen, you can store garlic 10-12 months.

Source:

http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17237

Comment: We do exactly what hobodave does: dark pantry, rarely do we have it so long it gets a chance to go bad.  One thing I wanted to add, if you find that your garlic bulbs are getting close to the end of their life and you can't think of a use for them immediately, you can also make roasted garlic and freeze that.  Roasting garlic in the oven is incredibly easy and the result is delicious!

Answer (score 2):

This technique works for garlic, as well as fresh ginger root: use a small grater or zester on the garlic and arrange the pulp on a piece of plastic wrap. Roll the garlic in the plastic wrap and twist the ends so it roughly resembles a long tootsie roll and freeze. When you want to use garlic, snap off a piece and add it to your dish.

This would probably also work with minced or sliced garlic.