# Why should you remove the core of garlic?

Tags: garlic

I have read it is better to remove the core of a clove of garlic. I actually see no reason for doing this. Does it have a different flavor, or is there some other good reason for it?

-edit-
In addition to the question as reaction to the answer 'because the green middle is bitter', I was wondering: 
-Then should you only remove the core when it is green, and not if the garlic is still very young?
-Is there some easy way to remove this core?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5031/should-one-always-use-the-whole-garlic-clove

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The green shoot in the middle of a clove of garlic is said to have a somewhat bitter flavor.

Comment: Would that mean that you do not have to remove it if the garlic is very young and does not have a green core jet?

Comment: You don't have to remove it at all if you don't want to. And whether you choose to might depend on what you're going to do with the garlic. If you prefer the flavor and/or appearance with the core removed, take it out. If not, don't feel like you need to do it just because somebody on TV did -- it won't hurt you.

Answer (score 3):

The major question isn't if this minimum part of a small garlic clove is or is'nt bitter (of course it is bitter, but normally we dont taste it apart). The major question is if its perceptible in your final product. So it may also depend on how you process the clove, if you cook or fry it, how much cloves you apply and wich kind of spices you combine with the garlic.

Lets remember nutmeg: just a bit more than nothing gives you excellent results, but two bits more than nothing turns your favorite plate in a terrible, inconsumable experience.

Answer (score 0):

I remove the green from inside the garlic. Otherwise, and pardon me for saying, it comes back to haunt me the rest of the night.